# OpenGL Compute shader sync different work groups

Tags: opengl, synchronization, compute-shader

If you have a compute shader where different work groups in the same dispatch are put in a continuous loop and you want to signal them all to exit said loop by any of them setting a flag.  Is this actually possible?

I've tried using a flag in an SSBO marked both coherent and volatile to trigger their exit.  Which sometimes doesn't work on AMD it seems.  When one of the work groups wants to trigger all of them to exit I simply set the flag from zero to one directly (as it doesn't matter as long as someone sets it) with no use of atomics and call a memoryBarrier() afterwards.

From the documentation of memoryBarrier() it seems to me like it will guarantee the eventual visibility of the set to other work groups within the same dispatch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From the documentation of memoryBarrier() it seems to me like it will guarantee the eventual visibility of the set to other work groups within the same dispatch?

Visibility, yes. But what about the *execution* of them?

Do you have any guarantees that the work group that will trigger this shutdown will be executed alongside the looping work groups? No.

There are no ordering guarantees *at all* between invocations from different work groups. So it is entirely possible that the GPU will fill all of its execution time with the looping work groups. Which means that they will wait for a signal that will *never* come.

Compute shaders offer no guarantees that all threads will progress. And therefore, you cannot write code that assumes they will. The only tool to control the execution of compute shaders is `barrier`, and that only controls the execution of invocations *within* a work group.

Comment: Thank you, great answer!  I wish the standard OpenGL documentation included this.  I needed exactly this to be stated to be sure of the correct mental model for this.

Comment: @iam: "*I wish the standard OpenGL documentation included this.*" It *does* include this. The OpenGL standard says, very clearly, "work groups are executed completely independently and in unspecified order." All I did was restate that with more words.

Comment: ok I obviously wish it had used slightly more words like you did to make me 'feel' more confident about the understanding of this! :)  And to be fair maybe it's a case that its not well confirmed/understood by other examples outside of this.