# OpenGL Compute Shader synchronization between groups

Tags: multithreading, opengl, glsl, compute-shader

I'm trying to make a global linked list for Forward+ Shading, but there's some

difficulties during the implementation.

For each group in compute shader, it has a shared variable: a local index array, and this array has variable length(capacity is constant, but the content is not). Here's the example:

shared int array[1024]; // the declaration in GLSL

shared int length; // it is also a shared variable in work group.

Group 0: length = 4, array = 3, 5, 7, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1.... (-1 = not valid)

Group 1: length = 2, array = 1, 6, -1, -1, -1....

Group 2: length = 1, array = 8, -1, -1, -1, -1....

Now I want to merge these indices into a global index array. i.e. a Shader Storage Buffer Object. The order is based on group index:

Global index array: 3, 5, 7, 1, 1, 6, 8, -1, -1, -1 ......

The difficulty is, I don't know how to sync between different groups. Since barrier() in OpenGL only guarantees synchronization in the same group.

And I found the in other post said OpenGL doesn't support synchronization between different groups.

[OpenGL Compute shader sync different work groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139989/opengl-compute-shader-sync-different-work-groups)

So, my question is. Is there anyway to achieve my goal?

For example, can I declare some Shader Storage Buffer Object, such as the latest group id that has finished updating and the offset of the global index array?

example:

```
unit latestGroupIDUpdated = -1; // a SSBO
unit globalIdxOffset = 0; // a SSBO
in each group:
while( myGroupId - 1 != latestGroupIDUpdated )
{ //keep waiting  }

// my previous group has updated the global list
globalIdxOffset+= myArrayLength;
latestGroupIDUpdated = myGroupId;
//now start appending the local index array into global index array
```

Will this attempt works? Or will it failed and why?

If it will fail, what kind of approach is advised?

Comment: When you say "group", you mean "workgroup", right? If so, workgroups cannot have different "length"s. If by "length", you are referring to the number of invocations per group.

Comment: yes, group means workgroup

Comment: And the different lengths?

Comment: yes, group means workgroup. The length, however, is not the invocation. What I mean is each workgroup have its own shared variable: idxarray[ 1024 ], so the capacity is constant, but the valid length is not.

Comment: the formal declaration in GLSL is: shared int indexarray[1024];

Comment: So how do work groups get a "length"?

Comment: It is calculated in the same compute shader, you can assume that it has been set before array merging.
The step in this compute shader is 1.for each group, calculate its local index array 2.merge the array in each groups into a SSBO index array

Comment: The length is also a shared variable in group.

Comment: OK, could you actually just post your shader and the algorithm you're trying to implement? This thing where I ask you for information in bits and pieces isn't working.

Comment: [link](http://paste.ofcode.org/37rpSpbKeL7GTmFJNwCLnUU) I didn't write this code. It is just for reference. visibleLightIndices = array in work group
VisibleLightIndicesBuffer = SSBO global index array

Comment: Note that this code just paste all the local arrays into the global index array instead of truncating the invalid indices in these arrays.

Comment: The pasting array is after line 167.

Answer (score 0):

By the look of it, it looks like you organized your LOCAL GROUP in 1D:

```
layout(local_size_x = X​, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;
```

If you called `glDispatch(n * X, 1, 1)`, you will have n groups. 
Process between n groups are also executed in parallel, thus you will not know the order of which each `groupID` is being updated. Using '`latestGroupIDUpdated`' will not work.

Here is my approach, you should utilize the built-in variable

```
gl_GlobalInvocationID (gl_GlobalInvocationID.x in our case)
gl_GlobalInvocationID.x = gl_WorkGroupID.x * gl_WorkGroupSize.x + gl_LocalInvocationID.x; 

---//gl_WorkGroupID.x;  [0, n) - 'n' : num groups you dispatched

---//gl_WorkGroupSize.x; X - size (3 in your example)

---//gl_LocalInvocationID.x; [0, gl_WorkGroupSize.x) - or [0, X)
```

You can use `gl_GlobalInvocationID.x` to index into your '`global`' SSBO list to store '`length`'. Something like:

```
GlobalLengthList[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x] = length;
```

All this is just to store the dynamic value '`length`' in group order in the '`global`' SSBO list. All of these '`length`' will be updated once you called `glMemoryBarrier()` in your C/C++ application.

After that you will have to modify this array such that it would store the "Prefix Sum" - inclusive - of the 'length' array. This process is highly parallelized. If you're trying to save time, you can do this in a separate compute shader. (I suggest looking this up if your length array is long). You can also do this on the CPU.

After you have your inclusive prefix sum length array (let's call it PrefixSumLengthArray), you will need to call `glDispatch()` again to dispatch as many shader invocations as the total 'length' value - the last value in your `PrefixSumLengthArray`. Then you will use `gl_GlobalInvocationID` to index into your new `SSBO` list to store your arrays. Something like:

```
 int i = 0; // index to PrefixSumLengthArray array get the 'length' upto and including.

 int j = 0; // index [0, length) to get the localArray

 if (gl_GlobalInvocationID.x < PrefixSumLength[i]) {
       GlobalArrayList[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x] = localArray[j]; 
       j++; 
 } else {
       j = 0; 
       i++; 
 }
```

That will synchronize between different groups for ya!!!

Comment: It will also get rid of all the unnecessary '-1' values.